# How can I apply the Shape Key Driver to the Pose mode?

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I made a Shape Key to fix the jaw.

I have tested it by moving the F-Curve and I can see it change when the value passed 1.

And when I go to pose mode and change the jaw bone and come back to the driver, I can see the driver value changed too.

So which means I have set the armature and bone right.

But the shape key just doesn't change at all!

I have to move the slider manually again for it to change.

So looks like the shape key's value itself was overriding the driver value for some reason!

Could somebody please be so kind and tell me what did I miss!?

Much appreciated!

[Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JPdQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click the field where you would enter a number and insert driver (menu option).
From there math can be written based upon other objects properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set the driver to the value property instead of the mute one.

[image]

Comment: I can't seems to set it! Could you please be so kind and teach me how to set it!? Much appreciated!

Comment: @PiggyChu001, (1) Delete the Driver: RMB on mute property in the Shape keys pannel and select Delete Driver. Then turn on the chekbox.
(2) Add new Driver: RMB on value property in the Shape keys pannel and select Add Driver.

Comment: @PiggyChu001. Realize that property connected to driver outputs are colored purple.

Comment: OK... I got it! Thanks trillions!